# Set background td(for specific class of td) based on value inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I converted xlms file to HTML file to embed it to my web page, but some conditional tags were not working, So I am trying to handle it using CSS/Javascript on HTML file.

I have column called `status`, In this column-cells, if the value is 1/2/3, I want to show it with various coloured bullets. (I will use background image in CSS(td)).

But the problem is td(which has no specific ID only css class), I want to get value in that td and according to value I will put background image. Code part which is generated for that cell is like below:

```
<td class=xl21627 style='border-left:none'>3.00</td>
```

How can I access all cells and change background of this cells based on value inside it.

Comment: I want to access cells with particular class, not all

Answer (score 3):

If all the target td's has the same class

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var imgs = {
        1: '//placehold.it/32/ff0000',
        2: '//placehold.it/32/00ff00',
        3: '//placehold.it/32/0000ff'
    }
    $('.xl21627').css('background-image', function () {
        return 'url(' + imgs[parseInt(this.innerHTML)] + ')'
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jmGbY/)

Comment: I believe that the TS means that the class should change based on the content in it (1/2/3)...

Comment: @LinkinTED in that case http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jmGbY/3/ or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jmGbY/2/ can be used